# Can we treat $\operatorname{span}()$ as an operator by taking the span of both sides of a relation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can we treat $\operatorname{span}$ as an operator by taking the span of both sides of a relation?

For example, does $A\subset B$ imply that $\operatorname{span}(A) \subset \operatorname{span}(B)$?

Comment: Yes, that implication is valid; it is also *very* easy to prove.

Comment: If you change $\subset$ to $\subseteq$ I think it works.

Comment: @K.defaoite Many people use $\subset$ for $\subseteq$.

Comment: @azif00 Perhaps, but I think this is rather imprecise.

Comment: Your question says "a relation". That is way too general to answer. If you are interested specifically in the relation $\subseteq$, write that in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The span() will map a set to a set. To be technical you will need some analogue of addition and scalar multiplication on the power sets of the space and then show that the span() is a linear map with respect to those analogues. Then it will be an operator in the more generalized sense, but still not in the strict sense.

Differing fields have more rigorous or more loose requirements to being an operator.

Also, the example given fails unless you allow equality in the subset operator. The counterexample is to take A to be a single non-zero vector v and B to be v together with 2v.